# LaTeX Figure Repository

Tags: repositories

I am wondering if there is a source website or repository for LaTeX figures. Many talented LaTechnicians have put many hours into solutions for making complex figures, even on this forum, and I'm sure would like them to be used by others, for academic or other purposes. Does such a webpage exist?

Comment: http://texample.net/?

Comment: and [this list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/74459/max-snippe?tab=answers) ;-)

Comment: and [this list too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot?tab=answers)